# Regexp to find the word "Linux" within a parenthesis contained in ""

Tags: regex

So i'm trying to create a regexp using grep to find the word `linux` as well as the rest of the whole line.

For example:

> "This is some text (this is Linux)"

would match the word `text` as well as everything else contained within the `""`

What i have now is

```
".*(Linux)*."
```

but it matches everything with a parenthesis rather than the `linux`

Comment: what is your regex?

Comment: @hadi this: ".(Linux.)"

Comment: okay, use this pattern: `Linux` without .().

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks, for fixing the formatting for me

Comment: this : `grep -e Linux` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

grep gives you whole line as output.

Simply `grep Linux <filename>` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this patern `.*Linux.*`

Maybe add a /gmi to have a case insensitive multi line and a global catch

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Could i ask why its formatted .*Linux.* instead of .*Linux*. ?

Comment: You say `.` you want to match any character then you say how many `*` is all. If you need help understanding / trying regex I recommend you check [regex101](https://regex101.com/)